# Remove 10 from input type text

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this HTML Code

```js
var number = document.getElementById("number");

function ClickFunction() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

function Grandma() {
  number.value = number.value - 10;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number" class="input-text-no-border-font-size-30-centered" value="0" />

<input type="button" onclick="ClickFunction()" value="Klick mich!" class="input-button-centered-box-general">

<p align="right">
  <input type="button" onclick="Grandma()" value="Kosten: 10 Cookies -> Die Gro&szlig;mutter (macht ein klick mehr)" class="input-button-right-box-general">
</p>
```

As you can maybe see i am working on a cookie clicker game. I want to make a Grandma that removes 10 from the current amount of cookies and so makes the user per click 2 cookies instead of one. I am fairly new tho. Any help is greatly apreciated

Small Edit: I dont know why but somehow the code works here on stack overflow but not on my local Website

Comment: What's the problem? When I click on the Grandma button the value is reduced by 10.

Comment: What do you mean by "makes the user per click 2 cookies instead of one"? Do you want clicking on Grandma change the way the other button works?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to increase the cookie value every time grandma get 10 then:

```
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var incremental = 1
function ClickFunction() {
  var value = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value = value + incremental;
  document.getElementById('number').value = value;
}

function Grandma() {
  number.value = number.value - 10;
  incremental ++
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use Replace function. As your input is a string.

Comment: How would you use the `replace()` function to remove subtract 10?

Comment: str.replace("10","")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).